# Trigger a child job after parent job has run multiple times in the day

Tags: jenkins

I have a parent job which runs multiple times in a day, I have a child job which has to run only once a day only if the latest staus of parent job is successful.
Can you please let me know, different ways of doing it.s

Regards
Jagdish

Answer (score 0):

Use Post build trigger

1. Trigger your child build if parent build is succeed.
2. Trigger one more child job from your child job to disable the job.
   (you can easily disable or enable jobs by using groovy scipts.)

Answer (score 0):

I would implement a simple counter + flag file.

Counter written to a file every time the parent job runs.
If the counter reaches **N**, create a flag file.
Use the [Conditional BuildStep Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin) and check if flag file exists.
If exists, and parent build is good, reset counter, delete flag file and trigger child job.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thnanks to you all for the ideas.I implimented this using a python script which compares current time with the time I want to run the job, if current time is less then it does not trigger the job and if it is equal to, greater than and less than one minute from runtime+1 min then it executes. So if my my designated runtime is 7PM, I compare current>7PM and current<7:01 PM.
So this way, even if parent job runs every 5 minutes, this child job triggers only once at 7PM. Use Trigger Remotely option to enable trigger remotely and execute this python script from parent job.